# Properly Joining Tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables that names StationTabs and Links in SQLServer2008.

```
StationTabs
------------
StationId(int)
Longitude(float)
Latitude(float)


Links
----
id(int)
StationStart(int)
StationEnd(int)
```

StationStart and StationEnd are foreign keys of StationId. I should get Longitude and Latitude values for StationStart and StationEnd with the same query.I've tried something like this;

```
Select Longitude,Latitude
From StationTabs, (Select * From Links ) As ST1, (Select * From Links) As ST2
Where ST1.StationStart=StationTabs.StationId  AND ST2.StationEnd=StationTabs.StationId;
```

This statement only returns Longitude and Latitude values of StationEnd.Can somebody help?

For instance;

```
StationId = 1, Longitude = 35,18, Latitude = 37,01
StationId = 2, Longitude = 36,43, Latitude = 38,88
```

In Links table;

```
id = 3, StationStart = 2 , StationStart = 1
```

For result,I have to get the values of

```
lonStart=36,43 and latStart = 38,88
lonEnd=35,18 and latEnd=37,01
```

Comment: Can you give a few rows of sample input and your expected results from your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to get the start and end lat/long values for each `Links` entry, you're doubling-up references to the wrong table:

```
SELECT
    ST1.Longitude as StartLong,
    ST1.Latitude as StartLat,
    ST2.Longitude as EndLong,
    ST2.Latitude as EndLat,
    l.ID as LinkID
FROM
   Links l
      inner join
   StationTabs ST1
      on
          l.StationStart = ST1.StationId
      inner join
   StationTabs ST2
      on
          l.StationEnd = ST2.StationId
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
SELECT Longitude, 
       Latitude 
FROM   StationTabs st
INNER JOIN Links lStart
    ON st.StationId = lStart.StationStart
INNER JOIN Links lEnd
    ON st.StationId = lEnd.StationEnd
```

If one of both (or both) can be null but you want to include this record anyway you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help but this didn't work. I got the 'Invalid Colum Name' exception.

Comment: @jacksparrow: have a look at the edited query. If that doesn't work you might want to copy&paste few rows of sample data which we can use in sql-fiddle. Then you should also include a desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Your sub-selects are utterly pointless, and should be written as regular JOIN operations:

```
SELECT Longitude, Latitude, ST1.id, ST2.id
FROM StationTabs
LEFT JOIN Links AS ST1 on StationTabs.StationID = ST1.StationStart
LEFT JOIN Links AS ST2 on StationTabs.StationID = ST2.StationEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Long,Lat From StationTabs where (StationId  IN (Select StationStart From Links) OR StationId IN (select StationEnd from Links))
```